# Postman : Running a request multiple times with different input data sets and based on the input the request body should be formed

Tags: javascript, json, csv, postman, multiple-input

I have a login API request with 3 parameters(say userName, password & remember) in the request body. In that 2 parameters(userName and password are mandatory, remember parameter is optional). The input is read from the CSV file during the runtime and data in the file is as below.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Now I want to use the same request for the given inputs and based on the input request body should be formed.
**Request :** `POST https://gateway.com/v1/login`
For example,request body should be like below for different iteration.

**Iteration 1,**

```
{
    "userName": "{{userName}}",
    "password": "{{password}}"
}
```

**iteration 2,**

```
{
    "userName": "{{userName}}",
    "password": "{{password}}",
    "remember": {{remember}}
}
```

**iteration 3,**

```
{
    "userName": "{{userName}}",
    "password": "{{password}}",
    "remember": {{remember}}
}
```

and assertions should be specific to each iteration based on the response returned. Can someone help how this can be achieved.

Comment: You haven't provided any details on what you've tried.  Where is the research?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iteration data for each line in the CSV is available in the special "data" variable.

This creates an JSON object (which is nearly in the correct format for your request).

```
{userName: "test1", password: "test@123", remember: ""}
```

The problem is that it reads the header of the CSV, so you will always have the headers as keys in the object, whether they contain data or not.

Therefore, you will need to clean this up before it can be used as the body for the request.

```js
let iterationData = data;
// console.log(iterationData);

for (var key in iterationData) {
    if (iterationData[key] === "") {
        delete iterationData[key];
    }
}

// console.log(iterationData);

pm.request.body.raw = JSON.stringify(iterationData);
```

If you set your body as raw/JSON but leave the content blank, then if you have this code in the pre-request script, it will create the body for you.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! In case if i have different JSON structure like '{
    "login": {
        "userName": "{{userName}}",
        "password": "{{password}}",
        "remember": {{remember}}
    }
}' , how this can be handled?

Comment: Define the body to include the login key using the iterationData as the value.  let body = {"login": iterationData}.  Then use the new body variable instead.  pm.request.body.raw = JSON.stringify(body);

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Prerequest scripts](https://learning.postman.com/docs/writing-scripts/pre-request-scripts/) and [Variables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/) in postman to store your csv content and then loop over it. (You can [set variables in prerequest scripts](https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-set-a-variable-in-pre-request-to-use-it-in-following-pre-request-of-same-request/38589))

Using setNextRequest should allow you to loop over your request ([example here](https://learning.postman.com/docs/collections/running-collections/building-workflows/#looping-over-a-request))

Finally, be sure to read this content that seems to answer your question :)

https://community.postman.com/t/running-a-request-multiple-times-with-different-data-sets/1064
or
https://community.postman.com/t/how-to-loop-through-array-and-use-its-values-in-a-request/6771